# Signature Does not match error on presignedUrl DigitalOCeane

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, pre-signed-url

I am using DigitalOcean for storing videos. I am using Firebase callable function to generate the signed URL with AWS SDK and sent it back to my app. When I use Firebase function to generate a signed URL then it gives me the Signature Does not match error.  The Firebase function is as follows-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.getS3SignedUrlUpload = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

   const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com');

   AWS.config.update({
     endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
     accessKeyId: 'mykey',
     secretAccessKey: 'mySecretKey',
     signatureVersion: 'v4',
     region: "sgp1"
   });

   var s3 = new AWS.S3();

   const s3Params = {

     Bucket: 'myappvideo',   //data.S3BucketName,
     Key: 'video14.mp4',//data.key,
     Expires: 60*60 // Expires in 10 minutes

   };

  var v = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
  console.log("PRESIGNED URL", v);


  return v;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally use getObject instead of putObject. Now it is working fine for me. But I don't know why it works, as I don't have any networking concepts. The line where I did the change is:

```
  var v = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
```

to

```
  var v = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3Params);
```